# How to achieve ToggleButton in WPF using Maui

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows

We have ToggleButton iniherited from Button which contains property like Content and IsChecked. It is used for having checked and unchecked states for buttons.

Is there a way to handle Toggle buttons in Maui?

I have tried using RadioButtons which indirectly handles ToggleButtons, I need a direct way to handle toggle buttons

Comment: MAUI has the Switch control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Maui doesn't implement the ToggleButton for the windows. You can create a custom control with the custom handler.